# What am i doing wrong in this python script?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
global_var = 1

def my_vars() :

    local_var = 2

    print( 'Local variable:' , local_var )

    global inner_var

    inner_var = 3

my_vars()

print( 'Coerced Global:' , inner_var )
```

I get a syntax error that reads

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

it on line 4

no idea what I'm doing wrong

Comment: global_var = 0 is what you need.

Comment: there is no error with your current snippet.

Comment: Agree with yopy. There is no error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

- You haven't initialized `global_var`.
- Also where is `local_var` defined?
- And you may want to use `,` instead of `.` in your last `print`
  statement.

Anyways, I don't see where that `SyntaxError` comes from.